# Trouble staying at same pagination setting when search input value is empty

Tags: javascript, events, input, pagination

Here is a sample of index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Students</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/design.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page">
      <div class="page-header cf">
        <h2>Students</h2>
        <!-- dynamically insert search form here (optional) -->

      </div>
      <ul class="student-list">
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/67.jpg">
                <h3>iboya vat</h3>
                <span class="email">iboya.vat@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/15/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Here is App.js

```
const studentList=document.querySelector('.student-list');
const page=document.querySelector(".page");

//constants used in displayPage function
//listItems ===54
const listItems=document.querySelector(".student-list").children;
const numberOfItems=10;

displayPage=(list,pageNumber)=> {
   const SI=(pageNumber*numberOfItems)-numberOfItems;
   const EI=pageNumber*numberOfItems;
   Array.from(list).forEach((item,index)=> {
      if (index>= SI && index<EI) {
         item.style.display="block";
      } else {
         item.style.display="none";
      }
   })
}

//number of pages to display
addPaginationLinks=(list)=> {
   const pages=Math.floor(list.length/10)
   let html=``;
   for (let i=0; i<pages; i++) {
      if (i===0) {
         html+=`
         <li>
            <a class="active" href="#">${i+1}</a>
         </li>`;
      } else {
         html+=`
         <li>
            <a href="#">${i+1}</a>
         </li>`;
      }

   }
   const ul=document.createElement("ul");
   ul.innerHTML=html;
   const div=document.createElement("div");
   div.classList.add("pagination");
   div.appendChild(ul);
   page.appendChild(div);
}




displayPage(listItems,1);
addPaginationLinks(listItems);



addEventListener=()=> {
   const a=document.querySelectorAll("a");
   a.forEach(item=> {
      item.addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
         a.forEach(item=> {
            if (item.classList.contains("active")) {
               item.classList.remove("active")
               e.target.classList.add("active");
            }
         })
         const pageNumber=parseInt(e.target.textContent);
         displayPage(listItems,pageNumber);
      })
   })
}


addEventListener();


addSearchComponent=()=> {
   const pageHeader=document.querySelector(".page-header.cf")
   let html=`
   <div class="student-search">
      <input placeholder="Search for students...">
      <button>Search</button>
   </div>`;
   pageHeader.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
}



addSearchComponent()

const search=document.querySelector("input");
const studentDetails=document.getElementsByClassName("student-details");



noResultsItem=()=> {
   const item=`
   <li class="no-results" style="display: none;">
      <h3>No Results Shown Found</h3>
   </li>`;
   studentList.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', item);
}

noResultsItem()


//select no results list item
//filtering student list based on keyup search value 
//array length is 0 if no match was found
search.addEventListener('keyup', (e)=> {
   const noResults=document.querySelector(".no-results");
   const array=Array.from(studentDetails).filter(student=>student.children[1].textContent.includes(e.target.value))
   //no items in filter 
   //make every student item dissppear, make noresults show 
   if (array.length==0) {
      Array.from(studentDetails).forEach(student=>{
         student.parentNode.style.display="none";
      });
      noResults.style.display="block";
      //show ones that match, hide ones that don't 
   } else if (array.length>0) {
      noResults.style.display="none";
      Array.from(studentDetails).forEach(student=>{
         if (student.children[1].textContent.includes(e.target.value)) {
            student.parentNode.style.display="block";
         } else {
            student.parentNode.style.display="none";
         }
      });
   }
});
```

Here is a link to my JSfiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/dt7q9h5x/1/

The index.html shown above actually includes, 54 li list items, but I only added one for the sample.

Heres my issue:

Although the number of list items changes depending on the value in the input field, when I delete what I typed in and the search input becomes empty, all 54 items re-appear, which isn't supposed to happen because only 10 items are supposed to appear on each page.

I want it to go back to the original pagination setting, which was initially set before I typed anything into the search input. This was originally set by the function displayPages(listItems,1).

When you go to JSfiddle, you can see there are 10 items listed on each page. Once you start typing, things seem to work, but once you delete everthing, then all the items just re-appear.

I think the code at the bottom of app.js where I'm writing code for the event handler must be the culprit here.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code, you didn't specify what to happen if the value of your search input becomes empty and this is where the problem occurs.

I changed your code a little and add a simple `if` statement and everything works just fine :)

```
search.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  // **************
  // Check to see if search term is empty or not
  // **************
  if (e.target.value.length > 0) {
    const noResults = document.querySelector(".no-results");
    const array = Array.from(studentDetails).filter(student => student.children[1].textContent.includes(e.target.value))
    //no items in filter 
    //make every student item dissppear, make noresults show 
    if (array.length == 0) {
      Array.from(studentDetails).forEach(student => {
        student.parentNode.style.display = "none";
      });
      noResults.style.display = "block";
      //show ones that match, hide ones that don't 
    } else if (array.length > 0) {
      noResults.style.display = "none";
      Array.from(studentDetails).forEach(student => {
        if (student.children[1].textContent.includes(e.target.value)) {
          student.parentNode.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          student.parentNode.style.display = "none";
        }
      });
    }
  } 
  // **************
  // Display the initial state if search term is empty
  // **************
  else {
    displayPage(listItems, 1);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution worked. Also, is it bad to use forEach like I'm using?